# Moq - How to step into the real method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to step into the real method using the test data as input.

When GetSurveyList is called it doesn't pay attention to the date I'm giving it. It always returns all three items I manually added to the mockModel. It should be checking the date and only returning those items that have a date that is equal to or greater than the input date.

If I step in I only get as far as the interface also. The next step in call should go to the code that implements the interface and yet it does not. Is this the standard behavior of Moq? I thought it would let you step in?

Here is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestHasListOfSurveys()
{
    var mockRepository = new Mock<ISurveyListRepository>();
    var mockModel = new List<SurveyList>();
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 1, SurveyName = "test1", DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2014") });
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 2, SurveyName = "test2", DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse("6/1/2014") });
    mockModel.Add(new SurveyList { SurveyID = 3, SurveyName = "test3", DeliveryDate = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2014") });

    string testDate = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(testDate)).Returns(mockModel);

    var testClass = new SurveyListModel(mockRepository.Object);
    var testModel = testClass.GetSurveyList(testDate);

    mockRepository.VerifyAll();

    Assert.IsTrue(testModel.Count > 0);
}
```

GetSurveyList from Repository:

public class SurveyListRepository : ISurveyListRepository

```
public List<SurveyList> GetSurveyList(String deliveryDateAfterInput)
{
    List<SurveyList> SurveyLists = new List<SurveyList>();
    string error = string.Empty;

    using (OrderingEntities db = DierbergsAppLib.Entities.EntityFactory.GetInstance<OrderingEntities>(
               new DierbergsAppLib.Entities.EntityFactory.EntityFactoryOptions()
               {
                   EntityNameInConfigFile = "OrderingEntities",
                   ConnectionStringCacheManager = new DierbergsAppLib.Entities.WebCacheConnectionStringManager()
               },
               out error))
    {
        DateTime deliveryDateFilter = Convert.ToDateTime(deliveryDateAfterInput);

        var SurveyList = db.uspOrderSurveyListAllStoresGet(deliveryDateFilter);

        foreach (uspOrderSurveyListAllStoresGet_Result viewsurvey in SurveyList)
        {
           // SurveyLists.Add( )
        }
    }

    List<SurveyList> all = SurveyLists.OrderBy(x => x.SurveyDueDate).ToList();
    return all;
}
```

GetSurveyList from model:

public class SurveyListModel

```
public List<SurveyList> GetSurveyList(String deliveryDateAfterInput)
{
    return _repository.GetSurveyList(deliveryDateAfterInput);
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code for `SurveyListModel.GetSurveyList`

Comment: Can you explain what `SurveyListModel` supposed to do when `GetSurveyList` is called? What is `testModel` returned by this method?

Comment: I added the GetSurveyList to the post.

Comment: GetSurveyList calls the stored procedure and the filtering logic is in the stored procedure. It makes sure the date for the survey must be equal to or greater than the input date.

Comment: @hyprsleepy nope, we don't need code of method you are mocking. We need definition of method you are testing

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Well spotted, I was completely confused for a moment there!

Comment: Oh, I think I added the right thing now. Check again?

Comment: I've updated my answer. My original guess about your problem was right. Does the answer fully make sense now?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best solution would be after reading your answer although it's clear what I'm doing is not a helpful test.

Comment: @hyprsleepy You have two options: either test that method or don't. The only reason to test it is if you might change the method in the future, or you just care about getting coverage of all your public methods. But if not, don't test it. If you want to test the actual repository, write tests for the repository instead.

Comment: @hyprsleepy please see my updaed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests are specifications of your code. Lets think what scenario of `SurveyListModel` behavior you are trying to specify by this test. In this case logic is very straight-forward:

> SurveyListModel should return surveys from repository for specified date

So, if you'll stop and think, then you should not verify dates of returned surveys. SurveyListModel responsibilities does not involve modifying repository response in any way. It should do following - pass date parameter to one specific method of repository, and just return repository response to caller. Nothing else. That's what you should verify.

```
var repositoryMock = new Mock<ISurveyListRepository>();
string date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetSurveyList(date)).Returns(CreateTestSurveys());
var model = new SurveyListModel(repositoryMock.Object);

var surveys = model.GetSurveyList(date);

repositoryMock.VerifyAll();
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(CreateTestSurveys(), surveys);
```

This test verifies that

- survey list called correct method of repository (if method was not called, verification will fail)
- correct date was passed (if SurveyListModel will pass different date to repository, setup will not be executed)
- survey list returned *exactly same* surveys which it got from repository (if SurveListModel will return different surveys, or modify repository response in any way, then assertion should fail).

You should understand, that it really does not matter what repository returns in this scenario. It could be surveys with any dates, or empty list as above. You should just verify that exactly same collection was returned by SUT.

NOTE: Use `DateTime` to pass date values.

Comment: SurveyListModel method GetSurveyList does the filtering though. But after that method is called the testModel has a count of 3 so the filtering hasn't been done.

Comment: @hyprsleepy OK, I get now logic of your test. Updated

Comment: I get the error, "CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)" I checked and the objects are of the same type and all the properties seem to be the same values.

Comment: If I take the CreateTestSurveys() and assign a variable like List<SurveyList> testData = CreateTestSurveys() and do CollectionAssert.AreEqual(testData,testModel) then it works fine and no error. I guess it doesn't like it being a function right there??

Answer (score 1):

```
mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetSurveyList(testDate)).Returns(mockModel);
```

This sets up your mock repository to return the full model when you `GetSurveyList(testDate)`, meaning that the date is ignored. Presumably `SurveyListModel` expects to only be getting back the `SurveyList`s for the date passed in to that method.

If you want it to do the correct thing, then only include a `mockModel.Add` line with the data you want the mock repository to actually return in your test.

However, now that you've posted the code you're testing, it's clear that this test is pointless. You're mocking out the code that actually does all the work! All the method you're "testing" does is return the mocked data.

Also don't use `DateTime.Today` as your test date or the test might not work tomorrow!

Comment: Are you saying if I take away the Returns it would do what I am wanting?

Comment: @hyprsleepy No, you're telling it to return the entire mock model. If you took away the returns, it wouldn't know what to return. If your test requires it to return certain data (e.g. only today's date) then you need to tell it to return that data.

Comment: Should I instead be not mocking out the code that does the work? I changed the test date to be set to "3/1/2014". I don't see how setting the data on the mockModel to be just the two with dates that match the filter accomplishes anything.

Comment: @hyprsleepy What do you expect to be doing the filtering? The real repository can't do it, because you're using a mocked repository. The mocked repository won't do it, because it just does what you tell it to, which is return all the data. The code you're testing won't do it, because it doesn't actually do that, it just returns what the repository gives it